# Is there anything wrong with this proof of uniqueness of inverses?

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, semigroups

I think there's something wrong with this proof for uniqueness of inverses in a set with an associative binary operation, but I can't properly word it.

> We take for granted that if $a \in S$ has a left inverse $\ell$ and a right inverse $r$, then $\ell = r$. It follows immediately that the inverse is unique. If $b_1, b_2$ are inverses of $a$, then $b_1 = b_2$.

The assumptions in uniqueness seem much stronger than in the lemma. The assumption is $a b_1 = b_2 a = e$ and $ab_2 = b_2 a = e$. But if we regard, say, $b_1$ as a left inverse and $b_2$ as a right inverse, then $b_1 = b_2$ by the same argument. The way I proved it is by a similar set of  steps.

Is the proof ok or am I missing something?

Comment: The proof you quote is okay. We are assuming that if $r$ is a right inverse of $a$, and $\ell$ is a left inverse of $a$, then $r=\ell$. Now assume that $a$ has two-sided inverses $b_1$ and $b_2$ (we are not assuming they are equal or distinct; we are trying to prove they are in fact equal). If you are a two-sided inverse, then you are also a left inverse *and* a right inverse. So $b_1$ is, in particular, a left inverse; and $b_2$ is, in particular, a right inverse, and hence by out assumption $b_1=b_2$.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. I appreciate it. The proof appears somewhat strange to me (using a stronger result to prove an ostensibly weaker result), but I'm glad that I'm not misunderstanding and it works fine.

Comment: Well, I don’t agree with the evaluation that the assumption (“if $a$ has a left inverse and a right inverse, then they are equal to each other”) is stronger than the conclusion (“if $a$ has a two-sided inverse, then this two-sided inverse is unique”).

Comment: The quoted proof does read very strangely. Taking some statement $P$ "for granted" has very different connotations from taking $P$ "as given": the former states that $P$ is true without proof, the latter states that $P$ is an assumption of the argument that follows.